# Pytorch Tensorboard SummaryWriter add_images from numpy array Not Working

Tags: numpy, jupyter-notebook, pytorch, jupyter, tensorboard

```py
from torch.utils.tensorboard import SummaryWriter
import numpy as np

logs_base_dir = "logs"
img_batch = np.zeros((16, 3, 100, 100))
for i in range(16): # 이미지 16장 만들기
    img_batch[i, 0] = np.arange(0, 10000).reshape(100, 100) / 10000 / 16 * i
    img_batch[i, 1] = (1 - np.arange(0, 10000).reshape(100, 100) / 10000) / 16 * i

writer = SummaryWriter(logs_base_dir)
writer.add_images('my_image_batch', img_batch, 0)
writer.close()
```

I run this code for just watching TensorBoard add_images example.
but KeyError: 'PNG' occured.

Help me.

Comment: What version of python and pytorch are you using, on what OS?

Comment: I usiing Python 3.8.12 and torch 1.10.2.

Comment: oh OS I am using is Mac Os (M1)